# reverse proxy with host machine authentication

Tags: nginx, proxy, oauth

I have the following situation:
In my company we can access O365 via authenticated devices only using Oauth, but I need to access web email at least from an old industrial PC device that cannot be joined to network because it doesn't meet the requirements (it runs Windows 7). I was thinking to add a network card to an approved machine, log on as an authenticated user and run a reverse proxy on the authenticated machine bind to added network card. The flow should be the following:
On the non authenticated device open a browser and connect to the IP of the network card added to the authenticated machine->the reverse proxy would detect the request, rewrite it with the authenticated user/machine credentials and forward to o365 server and serve the answer to the browser on the unauthenticated machine. All should work on Windows 10.
Is that possible at least? I was playing with nginx and stunnel but none worked as intended.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: What you described is more like a forward proxy, not reverse proxy.

Comment: Thank you! It may be, I am not very skilled in that part. Any suggestion for a software that would do that? On Windows